# Mongoose findOne() within a transaction : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$elemMatch' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm already many hours on this and I can't find a solution.

I'm using Node/Express and trying to run a Mongoose `(^5.2.0)` *findOne* with transactions. For the database, I'm running it in memory, with *run-rs*.

The collection is being previously populated with a valid document, which I can find using *mongo shell*:

```
rs:PRIMARY> db.lots.findOne("aaaabbbbccccdddd11112222")
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaabbbbccccdddd11112222"),
    "availableQty" : 0,
    "expirationDate" : ISODate("2019-01-10T15:10:29.455Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

But whenever I run this code below, I'm getting an error:

```
const save = async (lotId) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession()
    await session.startTransaction()
    try {        
        let lot = await Lots.findOne(lotId, session)
        console.log('result: ' + lot)

        await session.commitTransaction()
        await session.endSession()
        return lot    
    } catch(err) {
        console.error('caught error: ' + err)
        await session.abortTransaction()
        await session.endSession()
        throw err
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$elemMatch' of undefined
      at model.Query._castFields (node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3873:22)
      at model.Query.Query._findOne (node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1861:23)
      at process.nextTick (node_modules/kareem/index.js:333:33)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

And it seems it's not even caught in the catch(), since my console.log is never printed.

Comment: can you try change findOne(lotId, session) to findById(lotId).session(session)?

Comment: that workd! thank you Tomas. Idk why findOne would not work, though... it bugs me

Comment: no problem :) I added an answer with recommended texts that should clarify why it works and why it didn't work.

Comment: btw Tomas, when I tried to use `lot = await Lots.findById(lotId).(session)` it didn't work... I had to use as `Lots.findById(lotId).session(session).then( result => {`. Can I use it with `await`, somehow?

Comment: If you want to use `await`, you need to use `exec()` to return Promise. So the query would look like this: `await Lots.findById(lotId).session(session).exec();`. It is because Mongoose Query does not return Promise, but instead it returns thenable object. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: if I try this, I get an unexpected token syntax error at .session(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
findOne(lotId, session)
```

to

```
findById(lotId).session(session)
```

Mongoose uses Node.js MongoDB driver that has slightly different syntax than native MongoDB. Method findOne accepts object not an id (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne). So you can either use

```
findOne({ _id: lotId })
```

or simply

```
findById(lotId)
```

Both these methods return Query object, which has method session, that accepts session (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-session).

I recommend you to read documentation about transactions first to clarify other things: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

edit:
Also to use `await` with Mongoose, you need to use `exec()` at the end of the query, because Query object does not return Promise and only returns thenable (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

So correct query should look like this

```
const lot = await Lots.findById(lotId).session(session).exec();
```

Hope it helps,
Tomas :)